# htaccess RewriteRule issue using GET

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm struggling with this...
The RewriteRule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^media/viewMedia/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /media/viewMedia.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^media/viewMedia/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /media/viewMedia.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So, when the URL is /media/viewMedia/1, echo $_GET["id"] should result in 1, but output is blank? Of course if URL is /media/viewMedia.php?id=1, $_GET["id"] outputs 1.

Comment: You're rewrite works for me exactly as you've written it. I vaguely remember having a problem like this myself and I think it was something to do with Apache and PHP not properly communicating the modified query string. Try doing dumping $_GET, $_POST and $_SERVER and see if you can spot your id variable. Also the two queries could be replaced by one if you replace +)/$ with +)/?$ in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule with `MultiViews` turned off:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^media/viewMedia/([\w-]+)/?$ /media/viewMedia.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.